# What are some good resources for learning about video technologies on the web?

Tags: video, video-streaming

I know this type of question would probably get closed pretty soon, but I am having a hard time finding good resources to learn about video streaming, live streaming, or video processing etc online in many web development courses. There seems to be many questions very specific to a single topics and they are hard to follow if you are not in the field. Is there a beginner friendly path?

My day job is mostly about developing API and CRM software so I am not sure where to look. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: I'd suggest picking one aspect, such as the source encoding, the distribution, or the playback end, and focusing there.  There are a lot of technologies in use that go into video streaming.

Comment: similar to @Brad - but I''d say  look for a specific scenario you want to accomplish so you have a mental framework for how the jigsaw comes together. Are you wanting to do live (eg OBS, LiveStream, vMix) or on-demand (eg CloudFlare Stream or Azure Media Services)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is a good beginning:

https://github.com/leandromoreira/digital_video_introduction

Comment: this is great! Thanks.